# getRepository is null in phpunit test

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, phpunit

I'm running phpunit tests on some classes and I get this error

> Call to a member function getRepository() on null in
>   src/MyApp/MyBundle/CopyList.php on line 429

At that line is

```
$list = $this->em->getRepository('MyAppMyBundle:CopyList')->findByName($task);
```

from

```
namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;
use MyApp\MyBundle\Entity\CopyVirtualList;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class CopyList extends Action
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function __clone() {
        $task = $this->getTask();
        $this->__copy($task);
    }

    public function __copy($task) 
    {
        $list = $this->em->getRepository('MyAppMyBundle:CopyList')->findByName($task);

        if (!$list) {
            $list = new CopyVirtualList();
            $this->em->persist($list);
            $this->em->flush();
        }
    }
}
```

which is being called from the line

```
$clone = clone $container;
```

in

```
namespace tests\src\MyApp\MyBundle\Classes;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

abstract class TaskContextContainerTestCase extends TestCase
{
    public function testCloning()
    {
        $container = $this->createInstance();
        $container->setImmutable(true);

        $this->assertTrue($container->isImmutable());

        $clone = clone $container;

        $this->assertNotEquals($container, $clone);
        $this->assertFalse($clone->isImmutable());
    }

    protected function createInstance()
    {
        $task = $this->getMockBuilder('MyApp\MyBundle\Model\TaskContext')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMockForAbstractClass();

        $container = $task->createElement(
            $this->getContainerKind(),
            $this->getContainerType()
        );

        $container->setContext($task);

        return $container;
    }
}
```

TestCase is

```
namespace tests\src\MyApp\MyBundle;

use MyApp\Environment as Env;

require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/../../../../app/AppKernel.php';

class TestCase extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        try {
            $kernel = new \AppKernel('test', true);
            $kernel->boot();

            new \MyApp\Environment();  // init single env-instance

            Env::getInstance()->setContainer($kernel->getContainer());

        } catch (\Exception $e) {

        }

        parent::setUp();
    }
}
```

And

```
namespace MyApp\MyBundle\Tests\Units\Classes\Action;

use MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action\CopyList;
use tests\src\MyApp\MyBundle\Classes\Action\ActionTestCase as TestCase;

class CopyListTest extends TestCase {

    private $object;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp(); 
        $task = $this->getMockBuilder('MyApp\MyBundle\Model\TaskContext')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMock();
        $this->object = new CopyList($task);
    }

    public function testCreateInstance() {

        $task = $this->getMockBuilder('MyApp\MyBundle\Model\TaskContext')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();
        $container = $task->createElement($this->getContainerKind(), $this->getContainerType());

        $container->setContext($task);
        return $container;
    }

    public function testCloning()
    {
        $container = $this->createInstance();
        $container->setImmutable(true);

        $this->assertTrue($container->isImmutable());

        $clone = clone $container;

        $this->assertNotEquals($container, $clone);
        $this->assertFalse($clone->isImmutable());

    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

---

Comment: didn't you forgot a `use` statement for `EntityManager` in `CopyList Class`?

Comment: @RazvanBalosin yes, updated

Comment: What the class `TestCase`? (It is not a PHPUnit class according to namespace) What does the `createInstance()` method do?

Comment: @Timurib I've updated the question

Comment: How about sharing the actual test?

Comment: @localheinz updated

Comment: Three things: a) `__clone()` doesn't accept any arguments (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php#object.clone), and b) in `__clone()` you are creating a new instance of `CopyList`, is that supposed to be the same `CopyList` this method is defined in (cannot see an import that indicates something different), and c), in `__clone()` the local variable `$em` is undefined, you probably meant to refer to the instance variable `$this->em`.

Comment: @localheinz well spotted, and corrected in the question

Comment: Does `MyApp\MyBundle\Model\TaskContext` actually extend `Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager`? Looks like you inject an instance of the former into `CopyList` in the test. If you do, do you really have the type declaration in the constructor of `CopyList`?

Comment: No `TaskContext` doesn't extend `EntityManager`. What I have tried though is in the constructor for CopyList to include `TaskContext $task, EntityManager $em = null, CopyVirtualList $copyVirtualList = null`, but these are just my attempts to get this to work